# Mongoose upsert does not create default schema property

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Example document Schema:

```
var CompanySchema = Schema({
    created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    modified: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    address: { type: String, required:true },
    name: { type: String, required:true }
});
```

I'm using a common request handler for edit and create of "Company" documents:

```
exports.upsert = function(req, res) {
    helper.sanitizeObject(req.body);
    var company = {
        name: req.body.name,
        address: req.body.address
    };
    var id = req.body.id || new mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
    var queryOptions = {
        upsert: true
    };
    Company.findByIdAndUpdate(id, company, queryOptions).exec(function(error, result) {
        if(!error) {
            helper.respondWithData(req, res, {
                data: result.toJSON()
            });
        } else {
            helper.respondWithError(req, res, helper.getORMError(error));
        }
    });
};
```

But using this method, when a new document is inserted, `created`, `modified` properties are not saved with default values of `Date.now`. Now I can call `Company.create` depending on the existence of an id but I'm wondering why upsert does not use default values if a property does not exist on a new document?

I'm using Mongoose version ~3.8.10,

Answer (score 51, accepted):

What's going on is that none of Mongoose's validation, middleware, or default values are used when calling any of the "update" family of methods, like `findByIdAndUpdate`.  They're only invoked by calls to `save` or `create`.

The reason for this is that the "update" calls are effectively pass-throughs to the native driver, with Mongoose only providing type-casting of the fields based on the schema definition.

**Mongoose 4.0 Update**

Mongoose now supports setting defaults when a new document is created during an `update`, `findOneAndUpdate`, or `findByIdAndUpdate` upsert. Set the `setDefaultsOnInsert` option to `true` to enable this. This uses the `$setOnInsert` operator to create the defaults on insert.

```
var queryOptions = {
    upsert: true,
    setDefaultsOnInsert: true
};
Company.findByIdAndUpdate(id, company, queryOptions).exec( ...
```

Answer (score 8):

You may use `{ "$setOnInsert": { value: 31 } }` 
[Doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/)

Ref: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongoose-orm/WuJSqxPX8T8

syntax: `findOneAndUpdate([query], [doc], [options], [callback])` [Doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate)

example:

```
model.findOneAndUpdate(
      { username: 'john' },
      { "$setOnInsert": { points: '0' },
            $push: {
            "boards": {
                "account":req.body.account,
                "game":req.body.game                                        
            }
        }          
      { upsert: true},
      function(err, doc) {    

      });
```

Comment: Better to set the options `{upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true}` than relist the same defaults for every `findOneAndUpdate` call.  [See JohnnyHK's answer to this qestion.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25767756/404699)

Comment: Sigh I was wracking my head on why the setDefaultOnInsert was not working and finally saw that I had spelt it wrong. setDefault s OnInsert. I had completely missed that s.